# Deploy Strapi on Plesk

Tags: node.js, deployment, strapi, plesk

I’ve been trying to deploy Strapi on mi Plesk server. I followed a couple of guides I found on internet:

[Getting Strapi to run in Plesk](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/13452)

[Deploy Strapi on Plesk](https://medium.com/@devinred/deploy-strapi-on-plesk-848244c2dab5)

I don’t get any errors. However when I go to my domain it just sends back the default Plesk template. Any Idea of why is this happening?. Should I reference a document besides server.js on NodeJS or something similar?

Also I tried changing from production to development enviroment and still get the same error. Has anyone tried deploying it on Plesk?